# UiButton keep pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I have one little question, I have an uibutton I want that when i pressed the button a music start but when I pressed the same button again it stopped the music how can I give two actions to a button?? or maybe change the button when the music is playing !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a boolean as an instance variable, when you press the button change it to yes if its no, and to no if its yes. assign a different action to the different situations.

You can also change the state of the button, the button that was pressed is what is in the sender argument of your IBAction.

```
- (IBAction)playPauseAction:(id)sender
{ 
    if( _isPlaying )
    {
       [self pause];
        _isPlaying = false;

       [sender setTitle:@"Play"];
     }
     else
     {
        [self play];
        _isPlaying = true;
        [sender setTitle:@"Pause"];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTag:` function

Inside your target selector, just detect which tag is it and change the tag according to current state